# Using Ember-data RESTAdapter with different URL

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember data with different URL as i'm moving from ember-rails, to external ember application, so API url is `http://localhost:5000` and ember application is `http://localhost:9000`.

Now the problem is I need to include `x-appid` and `x-app-secret`, but whenever add `xhr.setRequestHeader()` for any of them, the `GET` request becomes `OPTIONS` request.

This code was working fine when i was using ember-rails on the same domain, is this the problem or is there something else missing?

```
ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    if (this.headers !== undefined) {
      var headers = this.headers;
      if (hash) {
        hash.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
          // Works fine
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.vendor+json;version=1');

          // Changes Request from GET to OPTIONS
          xhr.setRequestHeader('x-vendor-appid', '12412412');
          xhr.setRequestHeader('x-vendor-secret', 'aslkdfjaskldfjasd');
        };
      }
    }
    return this._super(url, type, hash);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser is sending an OPTIONS request because the domain of the request does not match the domain of your page.  This triggers [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) restrictions.

You need to respond to the CORS request from the server to tell the client it is allowed to make CORS requests to the domain by setting a few HTTP header fields. The browser will then make the original request. I have implemented this with ember.js/rails.